# AdControl not showing ads, even after uploading the app to the store

Tags: c#, uwp, ads, uwp-xaml

I Uploaded app an UWP app to the windows 10 store whil using AdControl to show ads in my app.

My Add Control doesn't show me ads, it just stay blank and throwing the next error:  "No ad available. No additional information""

In the dashbored - monetize I created ad unit name and got ad unit ID app ID and ad unit name as shown in here:[image: dashbord screen shot]

in the xaml file:

```
<UI:AdControl ApplicationId="78eefbba-92ef-466f-bec3-81e17f9c36d4"
     AdUnitId="332861"
     Name="adControl"
     Height="60"
     Width="480"
     Grid.Row="5"
     HorizontalAlignment="Center"
     ErrorOccurred="OnAdError"
     Grid.ColumnSpan="6"
     Grid.Column="0"/>
```

and wen i debug my app I'm getting:

> e.ErrorCode:NoAdAvailable

and in OnAdError event I'm getting:

> e.ErrorCode:NoAdAvailable
>   ErrorMessage: no ad available. No additional information

what did i do worng? and how can i fix it?

Editted:
the problem was solved, as Romasz comment the ad wasn't in the right size. 
another importent thing to notice is that in dev, even we the right size you may not see the ad until the app is published.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a problem with your AD sizes as I think - try to change to a size one of [described at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/uwp/monetize/supported-ad-sizes-for-banner-ads).

Also AD availability depend on country, it's hard to say if the problem is on your side or simply AD is not available from the Store. First I would check the size 480 x 60 is not supported, and thus there may be no AD available with that size. If the size is different than those on MSDN site, then there is chance you will get the error.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a size problem, phone sizes will also be displayed on desktop ([proof](https://1drv.ms/i/s!AnyzfOhy1UXrcQLZrFx_9M7hl1s)).

It is only a matter of lack of ads.

edit : period of the year seems to be a very high factor : my personal ads fillrate was around 10% during july and august, it is now about 85% since september (on PC, date of edit is the 14th of october).