# Why I'm not seeing ads?

Tags: c#, uwp, ads, windows-dev-center

I've made a UWP app, test values are working great but when I download from the store, ads are not showing up (and I've replaced test values with ad unit from dashboard).

```
<Advt:AdControl ApplicationId="*********"
                                                    AdUnitId="******"
                                                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                                    Height="120"
                                                    Grid.Row="2"/>
```

Comment: This is somehow what you are asking. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41779019/adcontrol-not-showing-ads-even-after-uploading-the-app-to-the-store

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two reasons could cause the issue that you have mentioned.

- The real ID(values with ad unit from dashboard) starts serving in 24h
  after your app has been published successfully.
- Another reason can be that you have not set the right size for the ad
  control, for more please refer to [**Supported banner ad sizes**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/supported-ad-sizes-for-banner-ads).